# What does "it" refer to (as we know it)?

Tags: pronouns

Over 4.5 billion years ago, the Earth’s primordial atmosphere was probably largely water vapour, carbon dioxide, sulfur dioxide and nitrogen. The appearance and subsequent evolution of exceedingly primitive living organisms (bacteria-like microbes and simple single-celled plants) began to change the atmosphere, liberating oxygen and breaking down carbon dioxide and sulfur dioxide. This made it possible for higher organisms to develop. When the earliest known plant cells with nuclei evolved about 2 billion years ago, the atmosphere seems to have had only about 1 percent of its present content of oxygen. With the emergence of the first land plants, about 500 million years ago, oxygen reached about one-third of its present concentration. It had risen to almost its present level by about 370 million years ago, when animals first spread on to land. Today’s atmosphere is thus not just a requirement to sustain life as we know **it** ― it is also — a consequence of life.

Comment: It’s quite simple. “It” means life is consequence of today’s atmosphere.

Comment: It can only refer to "life".

Answer (score 1):

The word **it** in that sentence refers to the word **life** that precedes it.

Restated not using **it**:

> requirement to sustain life (as we know life)

It means the form of life that we are familiar with.

It's probably worth mentioning that "life as we know it" is a fixed and very common phrase (try googling it). It allows for the possibility that there are other forms of life that we know nothing of. Maybe some of those forms will be comfortable here after we've ruined the atmosphere for ourselves.

Comment: 'Life as we know it' and 'Life, but not as we know it' are both 'cliches'; phrases that have become trite from overuse.